# Cannot read pdf with over 1gb size

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

Trying to encrypt multiple pdf of different sizes and I noticed that in pdfreader it throws out of memory exception if the pdf size is around 1gb, is there a work around here? I believe I have sufficient storage.

```
    //Encrypt the pdf
    using (Stream input = new FileStream(inputpdfpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (Stream output = new FileStream(outPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
            PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, pdfpassword, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS | PdfWriter.AllowPrinting | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS);
        }
    }

    File.Move(pdffilepath, Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, fileName));// move original files to another folder 
    File.Copy(outPDF, pdffilepath);// copy temp file (password encrypted) then use original name (temp file should be deleted)
    File.SetAttributes(outPDF, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Comment: _"I believe I have sufficient storage."_ - That belief is obviously unjustified. You may have enough RAM in theory, but do you have enough _available_ really?

Comment: I have 32gb ram installed isn't the enough? D: (Im not processing anything aside from that)

Comment: Did you profile your App? Are there some settings restricting memory? Just because you have 32Gigs installed doesn't mean the .Net Runtime is allowed to use all of it. Although I, too, would _expect_ it to have _enough_ available but who knows ...

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it.

Comment: can't seem to find the prefer 32-bit, but what i did is change in the configuration manager the Platform  to x64 ( had to create this) since it was set to  "Any CPU". I noticed tho the file size from 1.4 gb originally (not encrypted) became 300mb+ (encrypted with itextsharp) ._. which confuses me as to why.

Comment: Well, it may be that the encrypt method not ONLY encrypts them but also compresses them. Not like in a ZIP, but there may be compression in PDF that the original file just did not use, and the encryption tries do... well, o rit just stopped working when running out of memory and that is not the complete file.